# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (13,41) into shape (13)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to use tslearn library to analyze an audio numpy file. The file has a 45K row (45K audio samples) and 1 column, but each row has a nested object of (N,13). So the length of each sample is different while the features are the same (13 features). I want to stretch them all to 93 rows, which means if I print the shape of any of them, it will return (93,13).

data example: 
first nested object in the dataset, shape (43,13) 
[image]

second nested object in the dataset, shape (30,13)
[image]

I tried to use this tslearn library: https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gen_modules/preprocessing/tslearn.preprocessing.TimeSeriesResampler.html#tslearn.preprocessing.TimeSeriesResampler

but it will only change the column instead of the row. so basically if I have an array that is (44,13), it will change the array shape to (44,93) instead of (93.13). So I tried to rotate the array for 90 degrees and redo the analysis, but since the dataset itself is only 1D with 45K nested object, I had to make an empty list, use for loop to take out each object, rotate them 90 degrees and put them back to the list. Then I tried to change the list back to an array since the tslearn.preprocessing.TimeSeriesResampler only accepts array as parameters. However, it tells me that 'ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (13,41) into shape (13)' while trying to transfer the list back to an array.

```
import numpy as np
spoken_train = np.load("spoken_train.npy", allow_pickle=True) 
lis = []
  for i in range(len(spoken_train)):
  lis.append(np.rot90(spoken_train[i])) 
myarray = np.asarray(lis)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-440f2eba9eba> in <module>
      2 for i in range(len(spoken_train)):
      3     lis.append(np.rot90(spoken_train[i]))
----> 4 myarray = np.asarray(lis)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (13,41) into shape (13)
```

What should I do? If there is any easier way to rotate the nested array, please let me know as well. Thank you!

Comment: can you include a bit of test data, and the shapes of all arrays you are working with?

Comment: Hi@warped, thanks for the suggestion, I just printed the first two nested objects in the dataset and add them to the question. There are in total 45K of them. As you can see they have different number of rows but same number of columns. The highest number of rows in all these arrays is 93, that is why I am strenctch them all to 93.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this fit the bill:

```
lis = []
for i in range(len(spoken_train)):
    item = spoken_train[i]
    lis.append( item + np.zeros((1,item.shape[-1])))
myarray = np.concatenate(lis)
```

The `item` in the loop must have same number of columns though. According to your examples, all arrays in `spoken_train` must have the last dimension of 13.

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = np.copy(z) #since they have the same number of arrays
for i in range(len(spoken_train)):
  lis[i] = np.rot90(spoken_train[i])
```

Comment: Please consider adding some information or an explanation to accompany your answer.